# Miminum play services version required for FusedLocation API

Tags: android, locationmanager, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation

For using `FusedLocationApi` what is the minimum version of the play services installed on the device?

Also as LocationManager does not need play services, is there any minimum requirement for using `LocationManager`.

I want to get the Location of users using any API that covers as much devices as possible, that why I am concerned about the minimum requirement for both of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need `FusedLocationApi`. You can use plain Android API `android.location.LocationManager` instead, I am not sure it work 100% but you can try following with some customizations:

```
//start updates
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("location updates thread");
thread.start();
LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
String provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;//either gps, network, passive, fused
mgr.requestLocationUpdates(provider,1,1,callback,looper);
...
//stop updates
mgr.removeUpdates(callback);
thread.quit();
```

also make sure to request for location permissions before starting location updates

Answer (score 0):

*I want to get the Location of users using any API that covers as much devices as possible, that why I am concerned about the minimum requirement for both of them.*

You could start attempting to receive location via 
`FusedLocationProviderClient` if the device supports google play services. The api has methods that returns availability of itself.

In the case of not supporting, the `LocationManager` could be used safely on all versions. You can request location for network or gps providers as much as the device is able to use them.